# lost facebook likes after making changes to the button

Tags: facebook, like

I just changed the facebook like button to "recommend" and specified image and content in meta, and now have lost all my previous likes. Why did this happen and what can I do about it? Oh I also just made seo changes using a plugin for wordpress, don't know if that would make a difference by changing something in the structure. I'm using wordpress.

Comment: What did you change in the meta?

Comment: I changed the meta name description and replaced all the open graph meta tags with those generated by facebook in order to specify the image and content that is posted on the liker's wall. Didn't work anyway - facebook is still choosing the image and text to display.

Comment: I just removed action="recommend" from the code and now the like count is back up, but it says "like" when I would rather it say "recommend"

Comment: I can live with that, but I would really like control of the image and text displayed on the liker's post. This is a restaurant site and it's putting a picture of pie with a description of chicken... any ideas about that?

Comment: Please refer to this: (http://stackoverflow.com/q/6619542/590110). As to your second question, I am unfamiliar with Wordpress. You could wait for a more competent webmaster.SE member or post it on Wordpress Stack Exchange. (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) Lastly, you can answer your own question since you solved it yourself. Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

1. div class="fb-like" ... data-action="recommend". Otherwise, [generate new code](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).
2. Make sure url doesn't change (e.g. no url -> no url; one url per site -> retain that url)
3. Did you insert Like button code by hand or via plugin? If via plugin, [generate the code](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) yourself.
4. If you are stuck, [DEBUG](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)!